# Make div width fill the remaining space

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have left and right sidebar, then i intended to make some sort of content right at the center of it.
But when i make a new js file and define some styling width for it, i realize that my main content width just ignore the width of both the sidebar and go underneath it.

[image]

So my question is, how can i make the main content only have width based on the remaining space of the page?

**Router:**

```
import React from 'react'
import LeftSidebar from './components/sidebar/LeftSidebar'
import Main from './Pages/Main'
import RightSidebar from './components/sidebar/RightSidebar'

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

import "../src/styles/global.css"
const App = () => {
  return (

    <BrowserRouter>
      <>
        <LeftSidebar />
        <RightSidebar />

        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Main />}/>
        </Routes>
      </>
    </BrowserRouter>
   
  )
}

export default App
```

**Main Content js file:**

```
import React from 'react'
import SearchBox from '../components/search/Search'
import Styles from "../../src/styles/Main.module.css"
const Main = () => {
  return (
   <div className={Styles.mainSection}>
    <SearchBox />
   </div>
  )
}

export default Main
```

**Main Content css file:**

```
.mainSection {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I want the main content only have width of the remaining space in my page

Comment: is there a problem with setting a fixed width ? somethink like 20% 60% 20%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your main section you have:

```
height: 100vh;
```

that means 100% of the height.

So u can do something similar with the width:

for your sidebar:

```
width: 20vw;
```

then, for your main:

```
width: 80vw;
```

and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: flex` for parent component then play with flex-shrink or flex-grow. To set width use percents then `vw` (100vw is sometimes wider than the viewable area (because scrollbars))